# Shared pointers: pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Common pointers allows you to create pointer to pointer:

```
void foo(Object **o) {}

int main()
{
   Object * o = new Object();
   foo(&o);
}
```

Is there an analogous construction for shared_ptr?

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr <Object> *o) {}

int main()
{
   std::shared_ptr <Object>  o(new Object());
   foo(&o);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Unless you have special reason not to, it is easiest to just return an object by value or at least return an ownership transferring smart pointer by value. Taking a pointer to pointer or pointer to smart pointer in order to point it to a dynamically allocate object is usually not necessary in C++.

Answer (score 3):

Without testing this, I'm pretty sure you'd want:

```
shared_ptr<shared_ptr<T> > o(new shared_ptr<T>(new T()));
```

Edit: forgot the "new" after the first '(', and fixed non-standard use of >> in a template definition. (at least, not standard until C++0x)

Comment: And of course, the signature for foo() would be:

    void foo(std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<Object> > o);

Comment: Surely he's looking for something simpler such as parameter: `shared_ptr<T>* p` and implementation `p->reset(new T)` . Although even this looks clumsy to me.